# uint8_t does not take two digit inputs

Tags: c++, uint

This is my test code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    uint8_t a;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>a;
        if(a == 0) break;
        cout<<"Input is "<<a<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I execute (with my inputs), this is what I get

```
1
Input is 1
2
Input is 2
12
Input is 1
Input is 2
0
Input is 0
3  
Input is 3
```

Problem1: It takes input 12 as two separate inputs

Problem2: Condition if a==0 doesn't work

What might be the problems?

Comment: Short answer: yes, it is a bug in the spec :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uint8_t` is a `typedef` for an `unsigned char`. This means that one character will be read from `cin`.

When `"0"` is read it is actually the ascii value of the character `'0'` commonly 48, which is not zero hence the equality check fails.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I want to know if we have any datatype to store small numbers.

Comment: @neeradkumar, you can use `uint8_t` to store small numbers but not to read it using `cin`.

Comment: I want to read numbers from cin in my code. 
I guess I can take input to a int and then equal it to a uint8_t ?

Comment: yes, but check the that value of the read `uint16_t` or `int` can fit in a `uint8_t` before assigning.

Comment: is there any easy way to typecast int to uint8_t?

Comment: `uint8_t v = static_cast<uint8_t>(i);` where the value of `i` is a valid value (0 - 255) for a `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 4):

`uint8_t` is the same as a `char`, so trying to extract one from cin probably just gives you the next character to be typed.

The values to receive are then not character-translated-to-int, but the ascii values of the inputs. When you type 0 you're getting ascii \0 rather than int zero, so your test for zero isn't triggered. Try `if( a == '0')` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
if( a == '\0') doesn't work. But if(a == 48) works

Comment: My bad. Should have been `if(a == '0')`. Updated my answer.