# uint8_t need uint16_t to store values from stringstream

Tags: c++11, casting, stringstream, uint8t

reading an IP address from argv forces me to convert it to uint32_t

this function will do so:

```
uint32_t convert_string_ip_to_uint32_t (const string & string_ip)
{
    stringstream s(string_ip) ;
    uint16_t a,b,c,d; //to store the 4 ints
    char ch; //to temporarily store the '.'
    s >> a >> ch >> b >> ch >> c >> ch >> d ;
    std::cout << a << "  " << b << "  " << c << "  "<< d << std::flush;;
    return ((uint32_t) a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d);
}
```

But when I change the data type of a,b,c and d to uint8_t, the result will be rubish. Why?
e.g. string_ip = '192.168.1.10'

Comment: What do you mean by "rubbish"? And which "result" are we talking about—the output to stdout or the return value?

Comment: `uint8_t` is likely a typedef for `unsigned char`. `s >> a` means something very different when `a` is a `char` than when it's some flavor of `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uint8\_t does not take two digit inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308898/uint8-t-does-not-take-two-digit-inputs)