# thread assignment inside switch throw runtime error :

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc

writing sample c++ programs related to threads with multiple features in c++. The below program throws a runtime error at t1.join() using a switch statement however it is working plainly. Trying to understand, why it's throwing an error specifically with the switch. Does t1.join() not able to find the thread which started?

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


enum THREAD_CALLBACK_TYPE {
    FUNC_PTR = 1,
    FUNC_OBJ,
    LAMBDA
};

//1. function pointer
void funPtr()
{
    std::cout<<"From func pointer"<<std::endl;
}

//2. function object
class FuncObj
{
    public:
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout<<"From function object"<<std::endl;
    }

};

//3. lambda

auto Lambda = [](){
    std::cout<<"From Lambda"<<std::endl;
};

int main()
{

    std::cout<< "choose one option \n 1. "
    "Function Pointer\n 2. Function Object\n 3. Lambda\n"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"option: "<<std::endl;
    uint8_t option = 0;
    std::cin>>option;

    std::thread t1;
    //t1 = std::thread(Lambda);

    switch (option)
    {
        case FUNC_PTR:
        {
         t1 = std::thread(funPtr);
        }
        break;

        case FUNC_OBJ:
        {
          t1 =  std::thread(FuncObj());
        }
        break;

        case LAMBDA:
        {
          t1 = std::thread(Lambda);
        }
        break;
        
    
    default:
        break;
    }

    t1.join();
}
```

searched on StackOverflow. no such related questions were posted.

Comment: Why all this indirection? Anyway, I would use `std::future<void> future;` instead of `std::thread t1; ` and then use `std::async` to launch my functions. E.g. FUNC_OBJ would become `future = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ FuncObj(); });` and join would become `future.get()`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11308898/580083. The problem is that `uint8_t` is a type alias for some character data type (likely `unsigned char`). When you input `1`, it is a character `'1'`, which does not have a numeric value `1`. Consequently, your program goes through the `default` branch of `switch`, which then makes calling `join` invalid.

Comment: `uint8_t option = 0;` should be `int option = 0;`. There's no need for this micro-optimization, and it changes the meaning of the code. Unless there's a good reason to do otherwise, use `int` for integer types.